# Get Chrome on Android Virtual Machine to Trust Self Signed SSL

Tags: android-emulator, ssl-certificate, service-worker

I've create an [AVM](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) (Android Virtual Machine) in android studio for testing.  I need it to trust a self signed SSL cert we created for a website I'm working on.

When I open the website in the chrome browser on the AVM I get the following error.
[image]

This means I can't test a JavaScript service worker I need to add.

Any suggestions on how I can get chrome on the AVM device to trust the certificate.

I found I could open chrome from my host machine's terminal with
`./adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main`

So I thought if I added the following `flag` which works on chrome for mac it could work, but alas, it did not.

```
./adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://example.com.test
```